# Installed PHP using yum on Centos 6. Where's the Location?

Tags: php, centos, yum

I've been installing php using yum. I'd like to find my dir to php for compiling my mapserver. Can anyone tell me where's the location of my php?

Comment: belongs to serverfault.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so just run this:

```
whereis php
which php
```